# Firefox's headless screenshot doesn't work

Tags: firefox-headless

I want to use headless firefox to capture an image of a webpage.

In Linux, I use the command

/usr/lib64 / firefox/firefox - headless - screenshot/opt/touchyoo/web/xylmweb/screenshot / 201909 / tes1.JPG http://www.baidu.com
You can take screensaver photos,

But I use the command

/usr/lib64 / firefox/firefox - headless - screenshot/opt/touchyoo/bin/tes1.JPG HTTPS: / xylm.upload.mp.touchyoo.com/xylmweb/pages/mk.html?{" id ": 28, "mid ": 21}

it is Unable to save，

Can't you add parameters in url screenshot?

The above page is accessible on my server

Answer (score 0):

Put "" around the json object, for example

/usr/lib64 / firefox/firefox - headless - screenshot/opt/touchyoo/bin/tes1.JPG HTTPS: / xylm.upload.mp.touchyoo.com/xylmweb/pages/mk.html?‘{" id ": 28, "mid ": 21}’